# find Distance by latitude and longitude

Tags: asp.net

I am just stuck in the strange calculation.

I am trying to find distance by latitude and longitude by using this formula mentioned in this site.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

every thing is Ok there when I do it by calculator but when I started doing it by programmatically there is a difference in result.

here is my part of code

```
lat = Convert.ToDouble( (s3[a]));
                longt =Convert.ToDouble( (s4[a]));
                Avg_lat = pc._Latitude - lat;
                Avg_longt = pc._Longitude - longt;


            a_hold =( Math.Sin(Avg_lat / 2) * Math.Sin(Avg_lat / 2) )+ (Math.Cos(pc._Latitude) * Math.Cos(lat)) * (Math.Sin(Avg_longt / 2) * Math.Sin(Avg_longt / 2));
            c_hold = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a_hold), Math.Sqrt(1 - a_hold));
           // c_hold = (c_hold * 180) / 3.12;
            distance = 6371 * c_hold;
```

the problem is Math funcation here calculate the things in radian I want it in degree. so I just found a formula to convert radian into degree but that formula doesn't convert the calculation correctly.

I am just confused what to do bcoz there isn't any other option to convert radian into degree..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you converting correctly and in all places necessary? The correct radians-to-degrees formula is to multiply by `(180.0 / Math.PI)` and the degrees-to-radians formula is to multiply by `(Math.PI / 180.0)`.

You need to make a degrees-to-radians conversion on the arguments to `Math.Sin` and `Math.Cos`. You would need to make a radians-to-degrees conversion on the return value of `Math.Atan2` if you are trying to simulate the output of a scientific calculator in degrees mode, but the formula from the web page you linked to says to *not* do so (only convert the inputs).

Answer (score 1):

You can find a Java implementation of a function that computes the distance between two latitude-longitude pairs in [LinkedIn's datafu](https://github.com/linkedin/datafu/blob/master/src/java/datafu/pig/geo/HaversineDistInMiles.java#L41) project.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculator will have a radians option, so you verify your conversion.

Radians = Degrees * PI / 180